# Vote to close doesn't parse shorter question links

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, permalink

I just tried to vote to close by copying the *"Short permalink to this question"* link just below the question and pasting it into the vote to close box.  It came back with

> Unable to find a question id in your input - please enter a question url or numeric id.

Not a big deal, it was easy enough to trim the string down to just the question ID, but I thought it worth mentioning here anyway.

Comment: +1. Even appears when trying to close this bug report as a duplicate of itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok this should be fixed when we deploy next.