# The "linked" feature seems broken for short permalinks

Tags: bug, status-completed, permalink, linked-questions

It looks like linked questions are not detected/mentioned in the right sidebar when the short link format (`https://stackoverflow.com/q/xxxx/xxxx`) is used.

Example: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725370/is-there-a-way-to-emulate-correctly-replace-function-on-xpath-1/3725450#3725450).

Comment: Testing ♪ http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51176/146126 Well, reproduced it here to confirm it also is as such in comments.

Comment: Somewhat related is this one: [Vote to close doesn't parse shorter question links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64355/vote-to-close-doesnt-parse-shorter-question-links)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, this is fixed and will automatically start working once we deploy again.